# How can I run multiple Teradata SQL statements using a single string in C#?

Tags: c#, teradata

I know I can run them with one `ExecuteNonQuery()` per statement, but I am being asked to run a large text file with many statements.  A user who understands SQL (not a programmer) will update the file as the queries change in the future.

A typical file has a lot of `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE` statements with some `INSERT`s, `DELETE`s, and `UPDATE`s interspersed.  If I try this as I have below, I get `[Teradata Database] [3932] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.`  Adding an `ET;` after either or both statements still returns the same error.

```
using (TdConnection tdConnection = new TdConnection())
{
    TdConnectionStringBuilder conn = new TdConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        DataSource = "XXXXX",
        UserId = "ID",
        Password = "PW",
        AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP",
        ConnectionPooling = false
    };

    tdConnection.ConnectionString = conn.ConnectionString;
    tdConnection.Open();

    TdCommand command = new TdCommand(@"
        CREATE VOLATILE TABLE ABC AS
        (
        ...
        )
        WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(ABC_ID)
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

        DELETE FROM ABC;
    ", tdConnection)
    {
        CommandTimeout = 0
    };

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I see that "Multi-statement" is valid in the [documentation](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand~CommandText.html), but I can't seem to understand why it's not working in this case.  It does work if I run it from Teradata SQL Assistant rather than code.

I also understand that this is not the ideal way to implement this.  I know I can load the statements individually or use stored procedures, but I'm not being given a choice in the design in this case.

Comment: In Teradata each DDL-statement must be immediately commited, i.e. after each `CREATE VOLATILE TABLE...`. Only DMLs are allowed in a Multi Statement Request. Btw, SQL Assistant submits each statement individually using F5, when you try F9 it will fail with 3932, too.